# What difference: "Do I have it?" or "Have I it"?

Tags: grammar

What difference is between these phrases:

> "Do I have it?" and "Have I it?"
>
> "Do I have to do it?" and "Have I to do it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Do I have it" asks whether I possess whatever it is. This is the substantive meaning of "have." "Have I it" is simply ungrammatical; that is not the proper form for a question in English with respect to most verbs.

The verb "have" can also have purely grammatical significance in English. So "I have to do it" has nothing to do with possession. It means that I am obliged to do whatever it is. Here "have to" is equivalent to using the modal verb "must." "I have to do it" = "I must do it."

When turning sentences with modals into questions, the normal rules do not apply. The modal use of "do" to form a question is not used with the verb "be" or some modal verbs. Thus the interrogative form of "I must do that" is "Must I do that."

With the locution "have to," where "have" is acting much like a modal verb, you can follow either rule. You can make an interrogative from "I have to do that" with "Do I have to do that" (the normal rule) or with "Have I to do that" (the special rule). I must admit, however, that the second version sounds very odd in modern English. You may find it in old books, but it is not current in modern U.S. English. So I recommend that when you use "have to" to mean "must" that you follow the normal rule.

Comment: thank you! But what then with "Have I" construction? Where is it used in modern English? I can forget it and use "Do I have" everywhere? For example, can I ask like this: "Do I have done that?". Insead of "have I done that?".

Comment: When you are using "have" in its substantive meaning of "possess," you must not say "Have I it." You follow the regular rule for forming interrogatives. When you are using "have" in its purely modal role to indicate a perfect tense, you follow the special rule for "be" and some modals. "I have seen that play" becomes the interrogative "Have I seen that play?" This is admittedly confusing. In short, follow the modal rule when "have" is being used to indicate a perfect tense for the substantive verb. Otherwise, follow the normal rule.

Comment: now all is clear. "Have" as verb or "have to" as "must" are used with "Do". Last question: Is "Do I have done that?" absolutely not correct variant?

Comment: Absolutely **NOT** correct.

Answer (score 0):

"Have I it?" is wrong in modern English. "Have I got it?" would be an alternative; this form is much more common in British English than in American English.

I'll argue "Have I to do it?" is also wrong in modern English, though you will encounter constructions like this in older / antiquated English literature.